# Remove the previous select widget, when i update it with a new value in another select widget in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I will select a "date" in the select widget then an another select widget will appear depending on the previous value that i has selected. If i select the previous "date" select widget an another time, again a new Select widget is appearing but the previous Select widget still will be there. This has to be removed when i change the value in date select widget. Is there any solution how to do this ?

I tried curdoc().clear but it clears everything in the change. Only the particular widget has to be cleared.

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs,Panel
welcome_message = 'Operator selected: (none)'
text_banner = Paragraph(text=welcome_message, width=200, height=100)

def callback_print(text_banner=text_banner):
    user_input = str(cb_obj.value)
    welcome_message =  'Operator selected: ' + user_input
    text_banner.text = welcome_message
    tabs.reset.emit()
#reaction_time.reset.emit()

def my_text_input_handler(attr, old, new):
    print("Previous label: " + old)
    print("Updated label: " + new)  

    root= join(dirname(__file__),str(new))
    dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if 
               os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]

    available_date = dirlist 
    available_date += ['None']

    def update(attr, old, new1):
        root1= join(dirname(__file__),str(new),str(new1))
        dirlist1 = [ item for item in os.listdir(root1) if 
                 os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root1, item)) ]

        available_level = dirlist1 
        available_level += ['None']

        def update(attr, old, new2):


        user_data = pd.read_csv(join(dirname(__file__),str(new),str(new1),str(new2),'test1.txt'), sep=",",na_filter =None)             
        data = user_data.copy()
        #############################################
        ########PYTHON CODE ##########################
        ##############################################
        ##############################################
        # Create each of the tabs
        ### ALL Tabs
        # Put all the tabs into one application
        tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5,tab6,tab7])
        curdoc().clear()    
        layout = column(title,tabs,sizing_mode='scale_width')
        curdoc().add_root(layout)

    level_selection = Select(title="Select a Level : " ,value = 'None', options=available_level)
    level_selection.on_change('value', update1)
    curdoc().add_root(widgetbox(level_selection))


date_selection = Select(title="Select a date : " ,value = 'None', options=available_date)
date_selection.on_change('value', update)
layout1 = widgetbox(date_selection)
curdoc().add_root(layout1)


 # Put the tabs in the current document for display

 text_input = TextInput( title="Enter operator 
           Name:",callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(callback_print),css_classes= 
            ['customTextInput'])
 text_input.on_change('value', my_text_input_handler)
 curdoc().add_root(widgetbox(text_input))
```

[Select Widget Display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjWmo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on code that you added and comments discussion I think that this should work for you:

```
from bokeh.models import Div, Paragraph, Select, TextInput, CustomJS, WidgetBox
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Panel
welcome_message = 'Operator selected: (none)'
text_banner = Paragraph(text = welcome_message, width = 200, height = 100)

current_date = None

def callback_print(text_banner = text_banner):
    user_input = str(cb_obj.value)
    welcome_message = 'Operator selected: ' + user_input
    text_banner.text = welcome_message
    tabs.reset.emit()
# reaction_time.reset.emit()

def my_text_input_handler(attr, old, new):
    print("Previous label: " + old)
    print("Updated label: " + new)

    root = os.path.join(dirname(__file__), str(new))
    dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if
               os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]

    available_date = dirlist
    available_date += ['None']

    def update(attr, old, new1):
        root1 = os.path.join(dirname(__file__), str(new), str(new1))
        dirlist1 = [ item for item in os.listdir(root1) if
                 os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root1, item)) ]

        available_level = dirlist1
        available_level += ['None']

        global current_date
        if current_date is not None:
            layout1.children.remove(layout1.children[0])

        def update(attr, old, new2):
            user_data = pd.read_csv(join(dirname(__file__), str(new), str(new1), str(new2), 'test1.txt'), sep = ",", na_filter = None)
            data = user_data.copy()
            #############################################
            ########PYTHON CODE ##########################
            ##############################################
            ##############################################
            # Create each of the tabs
            # ## ALL Tabs
            # Put all the tabs into one application
            tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7])
            curdoc().clear()
            layout = column(title, tabs, sizing_mode = 'scale_width')
            curdoc().add_root(layout)

        level_selection = Select(title = "Select a Level : " , value = 'None', options = available_level)
        level_selection.on_change('value', update1)
        curdoc().add_root(WidgetBox(level_selection))
        current_date = new1

    date_selection = Select(title = "Select a date : " , value = 'None', options = available_date)
    date_selection.on_change('value', update)
    layout1 = WidgetBox(date_selection)
    curdoc().add_root(layout1)

 # Put the tabs in the current document for display

text_input = TextInput(title = "Enter operator Name:", callback = CustomJS.from_py_func(callback_print), css_classes = ['customTextInput'])
text_input.on_change('value', my_text_input_handler)
curdoc().add_root(WidgetBox(text_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this is what you want. Run the code using `bokeh serve --show app.py` (tested with Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import Select, Column, Div
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

day_start = datetime(2019, 3, 15)
day_step = timedelta(days = 1)
dates = [str(day_start + (i * day_step)) for i in range(0, 6)]

current_date = None
select_data = Select(title = 'Select a date', value = '', options = [''] + dates)
info = Div(text = 'Selected date: ')
layout = Column(info, select_data)

def update_info(attr, old, new):
    prefix = info.text.split(', level:')
    if len(prefix) > 1:
        info.text = prefix[0] + ', level: {}'.format(new)
    else:
        info.text = info.text + ', level: {}'.format(new)

def update_layout(attr, old, new):
    info.text = ('Selected date: {}'.format(new))
    global current_date
    if current_date is not None:
        layout.children.remove(layout.children[2])  # index 0 == info, index 1 == select_data, so we need to remove index 1 = dynamic_select

    levels = np.arange(np.random.randint(1, 4), np.random.randint(5, 7))  # replace this random levels with levels that you read from your csv file
    dynamic_select = Select(title = 'Select a level for date: {}'.format(new), value = '', options = [''] + [str(value) for value in levels])
    dynamic_select.on_change('value', update_info)
    layout.children.append(dynamic_select)
    current_date = new

select_data.on_change('value', update_layout)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: 'myapp
   |
   +---data1
   |    +---L1
   |    +---L2
   +---Date2
   |    +---L3
   |    +---L3 '     Like this there are folders in my system, i am selecting this Folders and loading the csv files present in the levels. The above method i am using is to select these files. Above what you told is exactly what i wanted but how to use this for my use case ?

Comment: My answer is exactly what you asked and I am sorry but it is completely unclear to me what you just wrote in your comment. Please always make sure you clearly specify your problem. Do you want a nested, 3-level Select widgets? So selecting a value always add a new Select until level 3? And when you change one of them all Select widgets below the current one are being removed and replaced with a new one?

Comment: Sorry, that i am unclear. yes, it is a 2 level nested Select widget. If I select date then level widget will pop-up showing level's present in that particular date. When i again select a new date then the old level widget has to be removed and a new level widget has to pop-up showing the respective levels in that date.

Comment: Your last comment confirms that the answer is correct: 2-level nested Select widget. What am I missing?

Comment: Your answer is correct but in my case the level select widget is present in the update function of the date select widget. I your case you are passing a static list of levels to level selector but in my case the list depends on the date selector. After selecting the date i will list the levels present in it and pass it to the list select widget, before that i don't know the levels present in it.In this case, how can i make your code to work  ?

Comment: See updated code: you just need to replace the **levels** with values read from your CSV file. Is this want you want?

Comment: I added the code in my question. Please, check it once. What edits i have to make to work as your code  ?